# Can you connect a microcontroller to USB without USB built into the chip?

Tags: microcontroller, programming

I have  a microcontroller that I don’t know if it has USB capability built in but I don’t have the money to get one that does. Is there any way of either software to directly read an IO pin or use electrical components outside of the chip to emulate the USB pinout?

Comment: your question is pointless ... why are you asking about emulating a USB device when you have a microcontroller with unknown capability .... find out if your microcontroller has USB capability first .... ask questions after

Answer (score 3):

You can get an FTDI cable USB-UART bridge and use the UART on your MCU to connect to it. After you install the virtual COM port drivers on the PC, it will appear as a terminal that you can read and send ASCII text (or other byte-wise messages with).

Comment: Or you can bit bang it for low speed.

Comment: Do you know where I can find out if my micro controller has usb support built in? I have the data sheet but I don’t know what I am looking for.

Comment: @user11937382 It depends on the microcontroller which you have not told us. Some manufacturers like ST put part-specific in a little datasheet and everything that is common among MCUs of a series in a massive reference manual.

Comment: I have a pic16f84a.

Comment: @user11937382 Also, you sound like a beginner. I do not recommend native USB...it is very very complicated...on both the MCU and PC side. UART is much more accessible.

Comment: @user11937382 I can tell you right now no PIC16 has native USB. Too weak.

Comment: Is it also too weak to handle uart?

Comment: @user11937382 No. Everything handles UART.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.

That said, an implementation of a USB HID using USB Low-speed mode has been ported to ATTiny. See here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/attiny85-communication-with-computer-through-usb

You can also use a USB-to-serial bridge (FT232 type) to communicate with a microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what stage of development you're in, but you're going to have to configure the UART port on your microcontroller, and wire it to an FTDI UART to USB chip. [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TXVRQ7V) is an example of a device you could use in a prototyping setup. It uses the FT232 series chip. [Here](https://forums.parallax.com/uploads/attachments/53156/85261.jpg) is an example circuit, in case you want to put this on a PCB. Make sure the I/O voltages are compatible.

On a Linux system, you can communicate with the USB port using the `screen` or `telnet` program. There are also many other command line programs you could use on to communicate with your microcontroller. On a Windows system, you could use Putty. On either system, you will have to install the FTDI driver.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search with the favorite web search engine reveals:

[V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) - A Firmware-Only USB Driver for Atmel AVR Microcontrollers