# Can you turn off usb protocol and use the USB port as a regular serial port?

Tags: microcontroller, programming

I am trying to make my pic16f84a micro controller communicate directly to my computer without a uart to usb bridge but I have been told that the way usb is handled wouldn’t allow me to do that with such a slow micro controller. Is there any way to turn the USB port into a regular serial port so that I could bypass that restriction?

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2012/05/07/16fusb-its-like-v-usb-for-the-pic-16f628/

Comment: This is the third variant of the question you have asked in two days. You first asked if you could connect PIC16 to USB. Everyone said you need a USB-UART bridge. Then you asked. Then you asked if you could program it using that bridge. Now you're asking if you  can do the USB-UART bridge without the bridge part. These are all practically the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you connect a microcontroller to USB without USB built into the chip?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/490383/can-you-connect-a-microcontroller-to-usb-without-usb-built-into-the-chip)

Comment: I had variations of the questions but was told that I can’t add extra questions to the the first question. My understanding is that you ask one question and stick to that question or you are going off topic and that was bad.

Comment: @user11937382 These questions are similar enough you can just Edit additional updates into your post.

Comment: just like an mcu with a usb peripheral cant be repurposed for something that logic block cant do, neither can your host computer turn a usb port into something that isnt a usb port, that is not how it works. if you want to do USB get another chip that is the bottom line if you dont want to do usb but want to do uart then use an FTDI or other usb to uart chip

Answer (score 2):

You will need a cable to connect the MCU up to the computer no matter what you do. If you were using USB transport end to end then obviously that would be a USB cable.

Since it appears that you want to use the UART out of the MCU to communicate and you do not want to put a UART to USB bridge IC on your circuit board then the solution you need is simply a different style of cable with the bridge chip built into the cable end. One that would do nicely is the TTL232R-3V3.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm)*</sup>

Comment: Just to make things clear, in case some reader misses "... on your circuit board ...": Such a cable **is** a UART to USB bridge. It is inside the USB plug.

Comment: @thebusybee - I edited the question to make that much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

No. USB port uses USB protocol and can't function as a regular serial port. You need a separate USB to serial chip or a.microcontroller that has support for USB protocol.